# ExtJs Combobox has value but it's displayed as empty

Tags: extjs

I have stateful combobox that contains value that is taken from state like that:

```
getState: function () {
    return {
        'value': this.getValue()
    };
},

applyState: function (state) {
    this.setValue(state.value);
},
```

If I choose one of combobox's options, close my application, open it again, when getState() is called, combobox still has this selected value. I can even pass it in event called in afterRender:

```
afterrender: function (combo) {
        this.fireEvent('someEvent', combo.getValue());
    }
```

and it's passed correctly. Everything looks good. Except of that, that initially combobox looks like it was empty when it has in fact value. How can I fix this? I've tried

```
this.setRawValue(state.value);
```

as second line of apply state, but it doesn't work.

Comment: May you reproduce it in fiddle.sencha.com? It is very hard to help you without looking at code.

Answer (score 0):

Component is stateful when the following config options are set:

- [stateId](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-stateId) : The unique id for this object to use for state management purposes.
- [stateful](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-stateful) : A flag/object which causes the object to attempt to restore the state of internal properties from a saved state on startup.

Plus to it, for state saving to work, the state manager's provider must have been set to an implementation of Ext.state.Provider.

[Ext.state.Manager](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.state.Manager.html)

> In order for this class to be useful, it must be initialized with a provider when your application initializes.

Out of the box there are two implemented providers:

1. [Ext.state.CookieProvider](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.state.CookieProvider.html)
2. [Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider.html)

---

Simple *example* of a stateful combobox - [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3708)

---

`Ext.form.field.ComboBox` extends `Ext.form.field.Picker` which extends `Ext.form.field.Text`

[Text field](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/src/Text.js.html) already adds `value` to its state:

```
getState: function() {
    return this.addPropertyToState(this.callParent(), 'value');
},
 
applyState: function(state) {
    this.callParent([state]);

    if (state.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
        this.setValue(state.value);
    }
}
```

Thus `getState` and `setState` (working with value) methods are *redundant*

```
getState: function () {
    return {
        'value': this.getValue()
    };
},

applyState: function (state) {
    this.setValue(state.value);
}
```

Side note, in `getState`/ `applyState` was not called parent method (looks like intentionally), which populates state with *height* and *width* from [Ext.Component](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/src/Component.js.html#Ext.Component-method-getState).